# Test Clover unpublished app(for Production environment) on clover dev machine or Android device

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, android-notifications, clover

I have unpublished production app and I need to test "App notification" in clover's dev device or Android phone before publishing it. I have already tested in dev environment. Is there any way so I can test it before published

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Install this APK in your Android device, then you will be able to install Production APK in your device for testing.
[com.clover.engine.apk](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=07160281334386362403)